# Convoluational layer is larger than max pooling layer

Tags: neural-network, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, yolo

I have been trying to convert an implementation of Yolo written in dark-net [found here](https://github.com/hollance/Forge/blob/master/Examples/YOLO/YOLO/YOLO.swift).

I'm having issues converting the original source code as the layers implemented in an alternative library seem to have an implementation gap as tiny_dnn requires more parameters to be set...

From the link above, line 44:

```
let output = input
    --> Resize(width: YOLO.inputWidth, height: YOLO.inputHeight)
    --> Convolution(kernel: (3, 3), channels: 16, activation: leaky, name: "conv1")
    --> MaxPooling(kernel: (2, 2), stride: (2, 2))
    --> Convolution(kernel: (3, 3), channels: 32, activation: leaky, name: "conv2")
--> MaxPooling(kernel: (2, 2), stride: (2, 2))
```

I'm trying to translate the above into c++ but I am missing parameters, as the swift code above must infer a number of variables... surely... as it seems to not require stating the following variables:

1. Window size,
2. bias,
3. wstride,
4. hstride,
5. padtype,
6. pooling size

Here is the code I'v tried in c++:

```
int w=416;
int h=416;
net 
<< convolutional_layer(w, h,3,16,16)
<< leaky_relu_layer(0.1F)
<< max_pooling_layer(shape3d(w , h , 3),2,2, core::default_engine());
```

however that results in an error between the leaky_relu_layer and the max_pooling as it says the output of the leaky relu layer does not match the input of the max pooling layer.

The parameters of the c++ are:

```
  convolutional_layer(size_t in_width,
                      size_t in_height,
                      size_t window_size,
                      size_t in_channels,
                      size_t out_channels,
                      padding pad_type             = padding::valid,
                      bool has_bias                = true,
                      size_t w_stride              = 1,
                      size_t h_stride              = 1,
                      core::backend_t backend_type = core::default_engine())


max_pooling_layer(const shape3d &in_shape,
                    size_t pooling_size,
                    size_t stride,
                    core::backend_t backend_type = core::default_engine())
```

Could anyone possibly explain why the output of my convolutional/leaky relu results in a different sized output than the input of the max pooling layer?